# Perl division gives different result to JavaScript

Tags: perl

In Perl I'm dividing two numbers, so:

`838041641/908376077`

This gives a Perl answer of:

`0.922571236978976`

But if you put it in a calculator (or use JavaScript) and the answer is:

`0.9225712369789765`

I need it to match the JavaScript answer. Is there any way to achieve this?

Another example is:
`838041641/152508066 = 5.49506437908668` (calculator = `5.495064379086677`)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to round to 16 significant digits. You can use `%g` for that.

```
$ perl -le'printf "%.16g\n", 838041641/908376077'
0.9225712369789765

$ perl -le'printf "%.16g\n", 838041641/152508066'
5.495064379086677
```

---

Do note that `%g` uses scientific notation for very large and very small numbers. If that's not acceptable, we could use `%e` to always get scientific notation, and use string manipulations to correct the format without introducing numerical errors.

```
sub round_to_16_sig_digits {
   my ($n) = @_;
   my $str = sprintf("%.15e", $n);
   $str =~ /^(-?)(\d)\.(\d+)e(.*)/saa or die "!!!";
   my $sign = $1;
   $str = $2 . $3;
   my $e = $4;
   my $decimals = 15 - $e;
   if ($decimals > 0) {
      $str = ("0" x ($decimals-15)) . $str if $decimals > 15;
      substr($str, -$decimals, 1, ".");
      $str =~ s/^0+\./0./;
      $str =~ s/\.?0*\z//;
   } else {
      $str .= "0" x (-$decimals);
   }

   return $sign . $str;
}
```

For example,

```
say round_to_16_sig_digits($_)
   for
      838041641/908376077,
      838041641/152508066;
```

outputs

```
0.9225712369789765
5.495064379086677
```

---

Note that doubles (used by Perl and JavaScript) have a little less than 16 digits of precision (log<sub>10</sub>(2<sup>53</sup>)=15.95...), so JavaScript is inventing information that doesn't actually exist, which is why Perl rounds to 15 digits of precision.

Comment: can't you just use `%.16g`?

Comment: @ysth, Maybe, but it sometimes returns "e" notation. I'll add to my answer.